# Does create-react-app support eliptic curve certificates?

Tags: reactjs

I'm setting up a https certificate for my react web page using create-react-app, and I've managed to make it work using an autosigned rsa certificate but not with an elliptic curve autosigned certificate (nor with a real certificate using ec signed by a ca).

I've made .key and .crt with openssl:

rsa (works):

`openssl req -newkey rsa:4096 -x509 -sha256 -days 365 -nodes -out my_rsa.crt -keyout my_rsa.key`

ecc (does not work):

`openssl ecparam -genkey -name secp384r1 | openssl ec -out my_ecc.key && openssl req -x509 -new -key my_ecc.key -out my_ecc.crt`

Also i've made a signed by ca certificate with elliptic curve as explained in:

https://www.namecheap.com/support/knowledgebase/article.aspx/9446/14/generating-csr-on-apache-opensslmodsslnginx-heroku/

But it's not working either.

I'm using a .env.development file with the enviroment variables:

```
HTTPS=true
SSL_CRT_FILE=../../.ssl/my_.xxx.crt
SSL_KEY_FILE=../../.ssl/my_xxx.key
```

but when trying execute `npm start` y get this error:

**The certificate "/home/ba/.ssl/my_ecc.crt" is invalid.
error:0608B096:digital envelope routines:EVP_PKEY_encrypt_init:operation not supported for this keytype**

Any help?

Thanks.